# Invoke action with a radio button click, MVC and JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have two radio button and would like to add a click event to the radio button such that when someone click on one radio button it invokes an action that is gong to render a partial view and this is my radio buttons:

```
<p>
<input id="SelectedInterestRate" type="radio" value="1" name="SelectedInterestRate"     data-val-number="The field must be a number." data-val="true">
<input id="Term" type="hidden" value="12" name="Term">
<input id="InterestRate" type="hidden" value="12.5" name="InterestRate">
<label for="SelectedInterestRate">Finance Test (12.5% APR - 12 Months)</label>
<input id="SelectedInterestRate" type="radio" value="2" name="SelectedInterestRate">
<input id="Term" type="hidden" value="12" name="Term">
<input id="InterestRate" type="hidden" value="18.25" name="InterestRate">
<label for="SelectedInterestRate">Direct finance (18.25% APR - 12 Months)</label>
</p>
```

and my Javascript looks like this(I know it is wrong)

```
$('[name="SelectedInterestRate"]').change(function() {
        alert("interesting here .......");
         var repayblein = $(this).closest("div.divFinanceDetails").find("input Term").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FinancePayment/SelectedRepaymentMethod",
        data: {
            InterestRate: $(this).closest("div.divFinanceDetails").find("input InterestRate").val(),
            RepayableIn: repayblein
        },
        success: function (partialView) {
            $("FinanceDetailsPlan").html(partialView);
        }
    });
    });
```

Anyone with a suggestion?

Comment: Just use `$('[name="SelectedInterestRate"]').click(function()`?

Comment: that doesn't work! tried it before. To clarify I need to send an Ajax Post to the server and populate a view with  SelectedRepaymentMethod (an actionResult in my FinancePayment controller)

Comment: Sorry, not `.click`, use `.change`

Comment: Doesn't work I am afraid

Comment: Is your other jquery things working?? You are sure you have linked jquery correctly??

Comment: @Anubhab yeah all other JQuery are working without any problem, like I said before I need to trigger an action on selection of a radio button

Comment: Even the alert message is not shown is it??

Comment: Is your code wrapped in $(function(){...});?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is:

```
$(':input[name="SelectedInterestRate"]').change(function() {
    alert("interesting here .......");
     var repayblein = $(this).closest("div.divFinanceDetails").find("input Term").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "FinancePayment/SelectedRepaymentMethod",
    data: {
        InterestRate: $(this).closest("div.divFinanceDetails").find("input InterestRate").val(),
        RepayableIn: repayblein
    },
    success: function (partialView) {
        $("FinanceDetailsPlan").html(partialView);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Cool, but some of your selectors are wrong? `FinanceDetailsPlan` has no `#`, `input Term` should be `input[name='Term']` and `input Interest` should be `input[name='Interest']`. Otherwise I can't see how it would actually work.

Comment: ahhhh yeah that is wrong basically I was trying to see if on a click ofthe button I can get anything hence an alert used I cleaned the code after and that part look more like you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your selectors. When selecting by ID, you must prefix the selector with a `#`. Also, some of your elements have duplicate IDs, which isn't good practice and makes selecting notoriously difficult.

**Also, what is `div.divFinanceDetails`? It's not even in your posted code**

With those points in mind, try this:

```
$('[name="SelectedInterestRate"]').change(function() {
    alert("interesting here .......");
    var repayblein = $(this).closest("div.divFinanceDetails").find("input[name='Term']").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "FinancePayment/SelectedRepaymentMethod",
    data: {
        InterestRate: $(this).closest("div.divFinanceDetails").find("input[name='InterestRate']").val(),
        RepayableIn: repayblein
    },
    success: function (partialView) {
        $("#FinanceDetailsPlan").html(partialView);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: the reason we have these radio button with the same name is that they are populated from the Database the code to bring them is    <p>
   @foreach(var interestRate in (IEnumerable<InterestRates>)ViewBag.InterestRates)
   {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedInterestRate, interestRate.ProfilesRef)
    } and there is a div around these with two hidden fields and a label that displays data as you can see in the code above

Comment: The same `name` is fine. Don't worry about duplicate IDs, just don't try selecting by ID on them :)

Comment: hahaaaa found out what I needed to do this line ('[name="SelectedInterestRate"]').change(function()  should have been (':input[name="SelectedInterestRate"]').change(function()  and that is all.